# How to retrieve a list from a list of dictionary passed to yamldecode function

Tags: terraform, yaml, terraform-template-file

I am new to terraform but I thought this should be very simple process however no example on internet.
I have specs of a vm

```
abc:
  - vm_name: "abc"
    template:
      cat: Apple
      image: "ubuntu18"
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
    cat:
      - red
      - geen
      - blue
```

This data is assigned to a variable using

```
cfg_vars = yamldecode(file(var.env_config))
```

All I want is to get `cat list members` (I think it is a list) i.e. red, green and blue in a variable `list_color`.

I checked splat [*] operator, but it is for map I believe. I assigned directly using

```
list_color = try(cfg_vars.abc.groups, [])
```

But it is not working. How can I get the values in terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use splat (`*`) expression:

```
locals {

  cfg_vars = yamldecode(file("test1.yaml"))
  list_color = flatten(local.cfg_vars["abc"][*]["cat"])

}
```

Comment: Here is a more challenging question if you get time, please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75895082/how-to-group-virtual-machines-in-ansible-inventory-file-on-the-basis-of-list-of