# How to group virtual machines in Ansible inventory file on the basis of list of keywords using Terraform and Jinja2

Tags: ansible, terraform, jinja2, ansible-inventory

How to create Ansible inventory file on the basis of list items chosen by user in VM creation config. The list items could be any words (let's not go to validation of list items for now). E.g. The following is the code for two VMs and the `cat` sub list specify the Ansible inventory group tag.

```
abc:
  - vm_name: "abc"
    template:
      cate: Apple
      image: "ubuntu18"
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
    cat:
      - red
      - geen
      - blue
  - vm_name: "xyz"
    template:
      cate: Orange
      image: "ubuntu18"
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
    cat:
      - red
      - blue
      - yellow
      - black
```

So far I am able to get the list using the following code

```
locals {

  cfg_vars = yamldecode(file("test1.yaml"))
  list_color = flatten(local.cfg_vars["abc"][*]["cat"])

}
```

1. One challenge is how to keep track of number of VMs along with its tags. VMs could be any number and tags could be any number too.
2. Second challenge is how to create groups in inventory file but groups should not be duplicated after checking all vms.
3. Third is assigning the VMs having that tags into those groups.
4. To print it in jinja2 format

Also I am not sure how to check and compare them for groups e.g. in the above case the logic should give me groups inside the inventory file as

```
[red]
%{ for group in red ~}
${ group }
%{ endfor ~}
[green]
%{ for group in green ~}
${ group }
%{ endfor ~}
.
.
.
```

Expected output if user picks above VMs configuration.

```
[red]
abc
xyz
[green]
abc
[blue]
abc
xyz
[yellow]
xyz
[black]
xyz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create a map, e.g. `inventory_map`, as below:

```
locals {

  cfg_vars = yamldecode(file("test1.yaml"))
  list_color = distinct(flatten(local.cfg_vars["abc"][*]["cat"]))
  
  inventory_map = merge([for color in local.list_color: {
    for vm in local.cfg_vars["abc"]:
      color => vm.vm_name... if contains(vm.cat, color)
      } 
  ]...)
}
```

which produces `local.inventory_map`:

```
{     
  "black" = [
    "xyz",  
  ]         
  "blue" = [
    "abc",  
    "xyz",  
  ]         
  "geen" = [  
    "abc",    
  ]        
  "red" = [   
    "abc",               
    "xyz",               
  ]           
  "yellow" = [           
    "xyz",               
  ]                      
}
```

Having `local.inventory_map` you could create a [templatefile](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile) to produce the desired txt file.

Comment: Thanks for help. This is similar to what I was looking for. Are the 3 dots part of syntax, or you meant to expand on it. I have to check the terraform map workings in detail today and try to finish it. In the mean while if you get time please elaborate your answer for terraform noob. Thanks.

Comment: @MianAsbatAhmad They are part of syntax. Called [argument expantion](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments).

Comment: I am happy to add more documentation so here is another question for you please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75899856/how-to-output-a-map-in-inventory-file-format-using-templatefile-terraform-functi

Comment: I got an issue. The `cat` parameter is optional but if I skip providing it then I get an error. Another scenario is if I add 3 vms, two with cat parameter and one without, then I cannot get any cat in host file. Any idea how to tackle it?

Answer (score 2):

Ansible can generate the groups for you. For example, create the tree

```bash
shell> tree inventory/
inventory/
├── 01-hosts
├── 02-constructed.yaml
└── group_vars
    └── all
        └── vms.yml
```

and provide the hosts

```bash
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
abc
xyz
```

with the dictionary

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/group_vars/all/vms.yml 
vms:
  abc:
    vm_name: abc
    template:
      cate: Apple
      image: ubuntu18
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
    cat:
      - red
      - geen
      - blue
  xyz:
    vm_name: xyz
    template:
      cate: Orange
      image: ubuntu18
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
    cat:
      - red
      - blue
      - yellow
      - black
```

Then, the inventory plugin *constructed* will create the groups

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yaml 
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
strict: true
use_vars_plugins: true
use_extra_vars: true
compose:
  vms: vms
groups:
  black: "'black' in vms[inventory_hostname].cat"
  blue: "'blue' in vms[inventory_hostname].cat"
  green: "'green' in vms[inventory_hostname].cat"
  red: "'red' in vms[inventory_hostname].cat"
  yellow: "'yellow' in vms[inventory_hostname].cat"
```

The play below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: groups|to_yaml
      run_once: true
```

will display the groups

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory pb.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [abc] => 
  groups|to_yaml: |-
    all: [abc, xyz]
    black: [xyz]
    blue: [abc, xyz]
    red: [abc, xyz]
    ungrouped: []
    yellow: [xyz]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
abc: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can also provide the dictionary via *extra variables* from any other path

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── 01-hosts
│   ├── 02-constructed.yaml
│   └── group_vars
│       └── all
├── pb.yml
└── vms.yml

3 directories, 5 files
```

The play below gives the same result

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -i inventory -e @vms.yml
```

---

- The group *green* wasn't created because of the error in the dictionary *vms* (*geen* instead of *green*).

Comment: Thanks @vladimir for the answer in detail. I am not very experienced and this answer is too advance for me. It may help some one or me in the future :) Appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help to move on. I know nearly nothing about Terraform.