# How to output a map in inventory file format using templatefile terraform function

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, ansible-inventory, terraform-template-file

I have a map variable given below `local.inventory_map`

```
{     
  "black" = [
    "xyz",  
  ]         
  "blue" = [
    "abc",  
    "xyz",  
  ]         
  "geen" = [  
    "abc",    
  ]        
  "red" = [   
    "abc",               
    "xyz",               
  ]           
  "yellow" = [           
    "xyz",               
  ]                      
}
```

I am trying to use the terrafrom templatefile function to get the following text file, Expected output

```
[black]
xyz
[blue]
abc
xyz
[green]
abc
[red]
abc
xyz
[yellow]
xyz
```

I tried

```
resource "local_file" "host_file" {
  content = templatefile(".hosts.yaml.tftpl",
    {
     color_groups = local.inventory_map
    }
)
```

and then in the hosts.yaml.tftpl file, I just tried to output the map but got an error. Please help.

```
%{ for key, value in color_groups ~}
${key}:${value}
%{ endfor ~}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Additionally your file extension is `yaml`, but the requested format is actually INI. Also, the content of the template file would not result in INI, but would result in valid YAML (although not an Ansible inventory file functionally similar to what is expected).

Comment: The way Ansible parses inventory files will still make it work, somehow, because it just tries to parse possible inventory files with all known inventory parser, but, indeed, you'll have to clarify if you'd prefer an ini inventory or a YAML one.

Comment: @MarkoE The error is `Invalid template interpolation value;
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for this answer to get my desired output

```
%{ for key, value in color_groups ~}
[${ key }]
%{ for v in value ~} 
${ v }
%{ endfor ~}

%{ endfor ~}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
    locals {
  stuff = {
    "black" = [
      "xyz",
    ]
    "blue" = [
      "abc",
      "xyz",
    ]
    "geen" = [
      "abc",
    ]
    "red" = [
      "abc",
      "xyz",
    ]
    "yellow" = [
      "xyz",
    ]
  }

  out_stuff = [
    for k, v in local.stuff :
    format("[${k}]\n%s",
    join("",
      [
        for s in v : "${s}\n"
      ]
    ))
  ]
}

output stuff {
  value = local.out_stuff
}

resource "local_file" "host_file" {
 filename = "${path.module}/foo.yml"
  content = join("", local.out_stuff)
}
```

this is what my output file looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to answer. I am sending the contents with existing data so if I assign the output of `join("", local.out_stuff)` to a variable and `xout` then how will I print it in `foo.yml`.

Comment: Or would it be possible that you send the stuff (map) to foo.yml in content as variable and then process it there using a for loop like you have done above.

Comment: Content sent to a file needs to be a string. You can use a template file to insert the string into an existing file. It wasn't clear to me what your existing file was or whether that was your intent. But template file function with one parameter should do it.

Comment: So if I say `outstuffprint = join("", local.out_stuff)` then do I have to loop through it in `foo.yml` file or just `$ { outstuffprint }` will do.